# Show the general solution of a differential equation by using a transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show the general solution of $\frac{du}{dt} + \alpha \frac{du}{dx}=0$ is $u(x,t) = F(x-at)$ by introducing the transformation:

$$\xi = x+\alpha t$$

$$\eta = x-\alpha t$$

Transform the original problem to a PDE in the variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ and solve this PDE.

How do I do the transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write 
$$u(x,t)=u\left(\frac{\xi+\eta}{2},\frac{\xi-\eta}{2\alpha}\right)=v(\xi,\eta)$$
then the partial derivatives of $v$ are
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial\xi}
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
+\frac{1}{2\alpha}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\quad
\text{and}\quad
\frac{\partial v}{\partial\eta}
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
-\frac{1}{2\alpha}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}.
$$
One can use them to rewrite the equation as
$$\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial\xi}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial\eta}\right)
+\frac\alpha\alpha\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial\xi}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial\eta}\right)=0
$$
or simply $\frac{\partial v}{\partial\xi}=0$. If you integrate this equation, you find that $v$ is a constant with respect to $\xi$, that is it only depends on $\eta=x-\alpha t$.